# Background command not displaying/showing from the stylesheet when using date picker js

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm new to this site having stumbled across it recently (and am loving it!) and was wondering whether someone can help me - I'm using Kelvin Luck's fantastic date picker and for some reason a background image is not behaving properly...

Here's the code straight from my CSS sheet:

```
a.dp-choose-date {
   background: url (../calendar.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   height:16px;
   margin:5px 3px 0;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:0;
   text-indent:-2000px;
   width:16px;
}
```

however when the background image is viewed through firebug, firebug doesn't show the style for the background image at all:

```
a.dp-choose-date {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   height:16px;
   margin:5px 3px 0;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:0;
   text-indent:-2000px;
   width:16px;
}
```

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? I've never seen this before!

The url by the way is http://www.s330042945.websitehome.co.uk/contact.php

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the space between 'url' and the '('. This needs to be:

```
background: url(../calendar.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Comment: Bl**dy hell - when you've been looking at it for ages, even the simplest things go unnoticed!

Comment: Haha...yeh it happens to the best of us. You're very welcome :-]